# SkyDrive is now OneDrive

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[OneDrive for Everything in Your Life](http://blog.onedrive.com/onedrive-for-everything-your-life/)

> Today we are pleased to announce that SkyDrive will soon become OneDrive.

We have more than a handful of questions about [skydrive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skydrive). Please re-tag them as [onedrive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onedrive) and make "skydrive" a synonym.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest solution would be for someone to retag one question with [onedrive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onedrive) then we can merge the tags.

This will have the effect of retagging the rest of the questions tagged [skydrive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skydrive) and automatically convert "skydrive" to "onedrive" when anyone uses it on a new question.

This has now been done.

Comment: I'm on it. Give me two minutes.

Comment: Okay. Flipped the tags on one.